# ошибка extension not available on this server - как исправить?

Tags: php, joomla

Перенес сайт со старой джумлы, на **Plesk panel**.
Перенеслось почти нормально, не считая вот этой ошибки:

> php Zip extension not available on this server. See
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Админка работает до момента редактирования стандартного материала.
Как сделать, чтобы админка работала, и интерфейс нормально прогружался?
Этот мануал я читать уже устал. Разбираюсь плохо.
В консоли пишет: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Joomla is not defined`

Comment: Ну, как бы, там все сказанно. `sudo pecl install zip` для линукса.

Comment: @E_p не понимаю о чем вы, линукс это на хостинге который?

Comment: Тут мне еще не правильно правили вопрос. Я не переносил сайт со старой джумлы на новую. Я перенос сайт на джумле 2.х версии на хостинге с панели ISP maneger на Plesk